# SlideDown div showing behind other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the `JQuery slideDown` method to show and hide a `div` which works well apart from the fact that it slides down behind other content on the page.  I have tried changing the `z-index` of the `div` but it makes no difference, despite the fact that the `divs` it hides behind have no `z-index` rule and all of the other styling I've applied to it does work.

Adding the `z-index` to the image made that appear correctly.

My js..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close1").click(function(){
    $("#what_is_audit_control").slideUp();
  });
  $(".slide_down_1").click(function(){
    $("#what_is_audit_control").slideDown();
  });
});
```

The html...

```
<div id="what_is_audit_control" 
       style="display:none; border-style:solid;border-color:#666;border-width:thin;width:600px; margin-left:20px;">
           <p>I hope this works</p><br/>
           <p class="close1">close</p>
</div><!--what is audit control-->
<img id="audit_control_main_tab" class="slide_down_1" src="images/tabs/audit_control_main.gif" alt="What is audit control?" style="z-index:99999999999" />
```

The inline styling will be moved to CSS pages after I have got it working correctly

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sXW7j/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the position on the element. z-index does only work on Absolute and relative.

Try:

```
<div id="what_is_audit_control" 
       style="display:none; border-style:solid;border-color:#666;border-width:thin;width:600px; margin-left:20px; position: relative; z-index: 2000">
           <p>I hope this works</p><br/>
           <p class="close1">close</p>
</div><!--what is audit control-->
<img id="audit_control_main_tab" class="slide_down_1" src="images/tabs/audit_control_main.gif" alt="What is audit control?" style=" position: relative; z-index:1000" />
```

Comment: thanks. The img is fine, was the div that didn't work but I changed the position on that instead which worked.

Comment: Yes I realized that when i read it little closer. Now the code is correct I guess. :)